# How to make a xmlhttp request POST setting a SELECT variable to a specific value

Tags: vba, forms, dom, xmlhttprequest, protocol-buffers

This is just the first obstacle I'm facing. It's likely I will meet a few more later on...

For now, I just want to POST a request to the site https://www.registroimprese.it/home, assigning specific values to two variables:

`<input name="_1_WAR_ricercaRIportlet_inputSearchField" class="span12 inputFiltroRicerca" id="inputSearchField" type="text" placeholder="Nome Impresa o Attività" value="" autocomplete="off">`

and

`<select class="aui-field-select input-block-level input-king-size selProvincia" id="selectPrv">`

I succeed to make a GET call to the site https://www.registroimprese.it/home.

```
    myURL = "https://www.registroimprese.it/home"
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", myURL, False
    xmlhttp.send
    
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
```

Then I collect the action and all hidden inputs

```
    Set form = HTMLDoc.getElementById("_1_WAR_ricercaRIportlet_searchForm")
    action = form.getAttribute("action")

    querystring = ""
    Set inputList = form.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each hiddenInput In inputList
        With hiddenInput
            If .getAttribute("type") = "hidden" And .getAttribute("value") <> "" Then
                If querystring = "" Then
                    querystring = .getAttribute("name") & "=" & .getAttribute("value")
                Else
                    querystring = querystring & "&" & .getAttribute("name") & "=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(.getAttribute("value"))
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
```

Finally, I POST the request with the desired values

```
        xmlhttp.Open "POST", action, False
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        xmlhttp.send "_1_WAR_ricercaRIportlet_inputSearchField=azienda&selectPrv=MI&" & querystring
        
    If xmlhttp.Status <> 200 Then Exit Sub
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
```

But, while the response gives the variable named `_1_WAR_ricercaRIportlet_inputSearchField` set to the right value, the variable `selectPrv` has not the desired value (i.e. the corresponding `option` is not `selected`). Sadly forecasted as the html tag hasn't got any `name` attribute, but only `id`.
Is there a way to solve this problem? (just the first of mine, though...)

Comment: `querystring = querystring & "&amp;" & ...` should be `querystring = querystring & "&" & ...`  The "&" separating the name/value pairs should not be URL-encoded.  However you *do* need to url-encode the values included in that post data.

Comment: The request on that page  is way more complicated than just a POST request, for instance the content type is `application/x-protobuffer` something I've never seen before.

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams, I edited the code for clarity, but it wasn't resolutive. I still don't get how to assign a value to the SELECT variable if the tag has no name.

Comment: Thank you @Musa, I'm pretty new to this, where did you get the content type `application/x-protobuffer`? do you think it's worth to investigate further over the content type?

Comment: For me using the dev console, the very first request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  The value of the dropdown is passed in the parameter `_1_WAR_ricercaRIportlet_filtroProvincia`   **But** it's a relatively complex request process - the first response is a redirect ("302 Found") and doesn't contain any actual content.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you @TimWilliams, how did you get it? Actually now the dropdown has selected the desired value. Maybe should I close the answer then, as it was on how setting the SELECT variable. Should I open another question? Because I didn't solve my problem, as you guessed. The response I get is similar to what I get from front-end, but the important part (the results contained in `<table class="table tableRisultatiGratuita">`) is missing.

Comment: I would probably avoid doing this using xmlhttp, and instead use browser automation with something like Selenium.

Comment: OK, thank you for your advices, I started using Power Automate by Microsoft, as input data are stored in Excel, and my task became straightforward.